# Nuxt doesn't minify the html entirely

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

While using `nuxt generate`, nuxt minifies the html as follows,

```
<!doctype html>
<html data-n-head-ssr lang="en" data-n-head="%7B%22lang%22:%7B%22ssr%22:%22en%22%7D%7D">
  <head>
    <title>Website</title><meta data-n-head="ssr" charset="utf-8"><meta data-n-head="ssr" name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no"><meta data-n-head="ssr" name="description" content="Website"><meta data-n-head="ssr" name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"><link data-n-head="ssr" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico">
```

As you can see the line breaks after `<!doctype html>`, `<html>`, `<head>` aren't removed. Why is that? And how do I remove the line breaks? Thanks.

`nuxt.config.js`

```
import path from "path"

export default {
  target: "static",
  // Target: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-target
  // target: "static",
  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    title: "Website",
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: "en",
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: "utf-8" },
      {
        name: "viewport",
        content: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no",
      },
      {
        name: "description",
        content: "Website",
      },
      { name: "format-detection", content: "telephone=no" },
    ],
    link: [{ rel: "icon", type: "image/x-icon", href: "/favicon.ico" }],
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [],

  router: {
    trailingSlash: false,
  },

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/content
    "@nuxt/content",
  ],

  // Content module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-content
  content: {},

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build

  alias: {
    "@/": path.resolve(__dirname, "/"),
  },
}
```